# Can I use the stereo channel on my mixer for my over head mics?

Tags: microphone, stereo, mixer, cable, input

I have a Phonic Powerpod 820 mixer that has 4 mono channels and 2 stereo channels. Can I route both of my overhead mics through one of the stereo channels? The stereo channels only have 2 1/4" inputs, and my overheads are XLR out, so I was wondering if I needed to get an adapter or 2 to make it work.

Here's a link to the mixer I'm using. http://www.musiciansfriend.com/pro-audio/phonic-powerpod-820-mixer?pfm=ac-m

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't work. Those inputs are design for keyboards or similar, therefore they don't have preamps.

Overheads are usually condenser mics too, so if yours are, these inputs won't supply phantom power for them to work either.

In order to make them work with those inputs, you'll need external pre amplifiers, but for the money, you'll be better upgrading your mixer.